# I'm creating a quiz with 5 random questions (out of an array with 20). I want to assign a picture to every possible question

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I'm creating a quiz with 5 random questions (out of an array of 20). I want to assign a picture to every possible question. The way I did that was using switch statements but that produces too much code as I have 20 questions. Is there another way to achieve this by using less code?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
const assignPictures = (value, questionID) => {

const addPicture = document.createElement("div");

 addPicture.setAttribute("class","imagesInQuestion")

  switch(true){
     
   case value === Array[0]:

      addPicture.innerHTML = `
   <img class="inlineImages" src ="/Images/Image.png">              
`
      break;
  
   case value === Array[1]:

      addPicture.innerHTML = `
      <img class="inlineImages" src ="/Images/Image2.png">              
   `
      break;

.....
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: And the answer is: VERY likely but we cannot tell since you did not post enough code

Comment: Also Please do not abuse the switch using `switch(true)` - that is an antipattern

Comment: `const images = ["image1","image2","image3",.....];  addPicture.innerHTML = \`<img class="inlineImages" src ="/Images/${images[quizNumber]}.png">\`` or add the image name to the object holding question and answers

Answer (score 0):

Use an object array.

```
var data = [{
      question : "Question"
      answer : "answer"
      image : "/image.png"
    },
    {
      question : "Question"
      answer : "answer"
      image : "/image.png"
    }]
```

Then create functions for inserting images and questions while clicking the button

Comment: There is no JSON here